# Implementing Login and Logout in multiple application

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, authentication, claims-based-auth, sso

I have a internal Sharepoint Site

1.I Login with my domainaccount\username and usually work .

2.Then i switch to TFS ,use my login id and password and check-in my code .

3.Later i go to another Non-Sharepoint intranet portal login where i maintain my personal documents .

After all my work is done by evening , i do a logoff in sharepoint . I would like to logoff of all the systems . How this can be achieved ?

Similarly i want to login only once to all the above mentioned system ,instead of logging in every time to SP,TFS etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at a reverse proxy that offers Single-Sign On functionality.  This can be achieved with systems like Microsoft UAG or, if compatible, ADFS.